# Installing apache.axiom in eclipse Windows

Tags: eclipse-plugin, axiom

I have a special requirement on using apache.axiom for webservice purpose. I do not know how to install the plugin in it. I have searched in the Eclipse market-place but couldn't find this package. Hence, I downloaded from Apache website and got stuck there as I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: http://ws.apache.org/axiom/
After I download the packet from there, where should I go next?

Answer (score 1):

Axiom is just a library. There is no Eclipse plugin for Axiom.

Comment: Since it is just library, how do I like have the

import org.apache.axiom.om.*;

pointer??

Comment: Ok. Now I have go to [AXIOM DOWNLOAD LINK](http://ws.apache.org/axiom/download.cgi) to download source distribution zip file. How do I continue from there to allow this plugin to be installed in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I already got it. Thanks @Andreas Veithen for the hint. It is a library. And it is a jar file. 
I need to go to "Properties" of the project > "Java Build Path" > "Libraries" > "Add External JARs" > Look for the axiom-api jar file.

Then it is linked. :))